# Windows 7 Backup on Windows 10 can be used for Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-backup

I would like to create full system backup, not just files. From what I see Windows 10 offers only Windows 7 Backup option for this. But what does Windows 7 Backup means in this case, can I only use this backup to restore backup on Windows 7 or can be restored also on Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although third-party products do it better, you can use
"Back up and Restore (Windows 7)" on Windows 10, and restore
using a Windows 10 boot media (or recovery disk).

See the following two Microsoft articles:

- [How to Create a System Image in Windows 11 and Windows 10 - 2021 Edition](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-create-a-system-image-in-windows-11-and/036110b8-66bb-4cc7-b9e2-2d66df27d236)
- [How to restore a Windows 10 system image to an existing or larger storage device](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-restore-a-windows-10-system-image-to-an/e20992ca-5641-4f7c-bb09-3895d0732162https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-restore-a-windows-10-system-image-to-an/e20992ca-5641-4f7c-bb09-3895d0732162)

**Backup** is done via the Settings app :
*Settings > Update & Security > Backup > Go to Backup and Restore (Windows 7)*.

**Restore** is done on boot with the following menu options :
*Repair your computer > Troubleshoot > System Image Recovery*.

More details and screenshots are available in the linked articles.