# Why does system image backup of C drive fail in Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, backup, windows-backup

I regularly take backup of my computer by creating system image of the C drive. I do so by going to Control Panel\System and Security\Backup and Restore and clicking the "Create a system image" link. Till date it was working fine, but once I updated from Window 7 to Windows 10 Pro, it doesn't work anymore.

Once I click the "Create a system image" link, select my external hard drive as the backup destination and click on Next, the list of drives comes up wherein the C drive, the System Reserved space and the Windows Recovery Environment are selected by default. As I don't need to select any other drive, I click "Start backup". As soon as the image backup process starts it fails with a prompt saying: *"There is not enough disk space to create the volume shadow copy on the storage location. Make sure that, for all volumes to be backed up, the minimum required disk space for shadow copy creation is available. This applies to both the backup storage destination and volumes included in the backup. Minimum requirement: For volumes more than 500 megabytes, the minimum is 50 megabytes of free space. For volumes more than 500 megabytes, the minimum is 320 megabytes of free space. Recommended: At least 1 gigabyte of free disk space on each volume if volume size is more than 1 gigabyte. (0x80780119)"*

Assuming, it's a matter of low disk space, let me specify the C drive that I want to back up the image of is of 930 GB and the external hard drive that is the destination of the backup is of 1.81 TB out of which 1.57 TB is free. So apparently, I don't see any scarcity of space. I've been using the in-built Backup and Restore of Windows for years with no problem. So, why is the backup failing now and how can I get it working? Or is there any other better way to do it? Please help, as it's been three months I couldn't backup my computer, and by any chance if it crashes now, I'll lose all my important installed apps and valuable official data.

[image]

[image]

**Edit:** As indicated by admin/moderator, my question might seem to be the duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1760380/windows-7-backup-on-windows-10-can-be-used-for-windows-10) post, but no, it doesn't answer my question. While it describes how to create backup in Windows 10 using the in-built tool, it doesn't answer why the backup tool fails while doing so, and what's the solution out of it. My question is specifically focused on that issue. Requesting admin/moderator to review my question and reopen it so that the issue may be resolved.

Comment: I do not recommend using "Back up and Restore (Windows 7)" on Windows 10. It's an old and deprecated product. Have a look at [AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html) or alternative third-party products.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Just one thing for confirmation. While creating the system image backup in an external hard drive or pen drive, does AOMEI delete all existing files in the external drive or does it retain them?

Comment: It backup everything to a *file* which can be later mounted as a disk. It deletes nothing.

Comment: I don't see how that's a duplicate. It's like "tool A throwing an error, answer, use tool B". Tool B may be viable alternative but it does not address the issue in OP and it doesn't explain the error. I vote reopen.

Comment: I reopened the post per the poster's request, but I say again that the "Back up and Restore (Windows 7)" tool is very problematic with many gotchas, as can be seen or our site.

Comment: @priyamtheone: The space referred to is also on the source drive. How much used and free space do you have on C?

Comment: @harrymc: Thanks for reopening the post. My C drive is actually an SSD of 930 GB out of which 808 GB is free. As mentioned earlier, I'm trying to create a system image of this drive and save it in an external hard drive of 1.81 TB out of which 1.57 TB is free. I also have another 500 GB HDD attached to my PC, but it doesn't have any OS installed and is solely used for data storing and viewing. I don't think the HDD is anyhow involved in the issue in question.

Comment: I think I have an explanation for your problem, so I put up an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The hint for the problem is perhaps the error message
"There is not enough disk space to create the **volume shadow copy** on the storage location".

Apparently, the backup program tries to create a shadow copy of the entire
disk before copying it to the target disk. The shadow copy storage is
a dynamic area that is limited in size by default to 10% of the disk.

The arithmetic is then :

- The shadow storage allocated space is 930 * 10% = 93 GB
- The used space is 930 - 808 = 122 GB

Conclusion : The shadow storage space on C is insufficient for creating
the shadow copy. You may verify this by running in an elevated
Command Prompt (cmd) the command:

```
vssadmin List ShadowStorage
```

You could use the command
[vssadmin resize shadowstorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/vssadmin-resize-shadowstorage)
to enlarge the maximal available space for shadow storage.
This will need some experimentation, as I'm unsure about the exact command
that you need.

Or you can use a third-party product that doesn't have such gotchas.
Have a look at
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.ubackup.com/free-backup-software.html)
or
[alternative products](https://alternativeto.net/software/aomei-data-backuper/).